# Mount cifs of shared windows folder problem

Tags: mount, shared-folders, cifs, smb

I've some issues with a windows share on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

1. Installed `cifs`utils`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
   ```
2. Created mountpoint

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/temp
   ```
3. Trying to mount a shared folder

   ```
   sudo mount -t cifs //fileserver/share /mnt/temp -o username=user,password=xxx
   ```

My problem is that the console hangs forever. I've waiting several minutes. If I enter wrong user/password it tells me Permission denied.

Update:

Response from Ubuntu Host computer:

```
nmap -p -v 445 fileserver -P0
```

host seems down / Filesharing seems to work though!

Ubuntu client computer (Inside vmware):

```
nmap -p -v 445 fileserver -P0
```

Host seems down / Filesharing doesn't work!

Maybe a lead: To autorize the fileshare I have to login on the domain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `dmesg | tail` show anything interesting at that point?

Comment: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because I have to ctrl-break the action to be able to continue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it to work.

I used the ip-address (192.168.1.11) instead of fileserver.

When ping:ing the fileserver name on the client I got ping response from another ip/computer (192.168.1.16) than I got from the host computer (192.168.1.11) !

Don't know why the dns name was linked to wrong ip on the client computer?

Comment: I believe the right way of going is **using the IP address** indeed. I will not go to the effort right now to prove it, but I remember reading that the cifs mount utility cannot handle the `//fileserver` notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is firewall issue for me . Install nmap on your ubuntu box with `apt-get install nmap` and run `nmap -p 445 fileserver` to see if the samba port is blocked by firewall or not.

Other way is to put -v `sudo mount -v -t cifs //fileserver/share /mnt/temp -o username=user,password=xxx`
 to see the verbose message from the mounting.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I got nmap response: Host seems down. I'm running this ubuntu inside another ubuntu host (vmware)

Comment: I think you have right about the firewall. Do you know how to open the port?

Comment: So, run `nmap -p 445 fileserver -P0`. 100% this is firewall issue!

Comment: If the machine is windows , go to windows firewall settings. If it is ubuntu , maybe you should stop apparmor

Comment: It works OK on the ubuntu host computer. It's the ubuntu inside the ubuntu that failes.

Comment: Ubuntu host computer: nmap response 445/tcp host seems down. (but filesharing seems to work)
Ubuntu client computer: nmap response 445/tcp host seems down. (filesharing doesn't work)

The fileshare is a windows domain. Maybe a lead?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

If you are using a standard VMWare Network-Configuration for that Virtual machine and following the documentation at http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-4B9B4A82-D0F7-4939-BD7B-B6BF92FF7350.html

> In a typical configuration, the New Virtual Machine wizard sets up NAT
>   for the virtual machine. You must select the custom configuration
>   option to configure bridged networking or host-only networking. The
>   wizard connects the virtual machine to the appropriate virtual
>   network.

Check out the VM's Network-Configuration and switch to bridged networking so that the VM has access to the same network-resources as your host machine.

Hope it helps.

NOTE: It was intended to be a comment, but I cannot do that yet :)

Comment: Thanks, the net on the virtual machine is bridge configured as you pointed out. It also got a ip-address in the same subnet as the fileserver. :)

Comment: Your solution was going to be my next answer :-D Glad you sorted this out.